# Memory error while parsing large XML files

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have to read large XML files to get matrices of the XML info arranged columnwise.

XML structure as follows

```
Several lines of no structured heading

<TimeStep TS="1">
<Particle PT="1">
<![CDATA[100,1000]]>
</Particle>
<Particle PT="2">
<![CDATA[200,2000]]>
</Particle>
</TimeStep>

<Timestep TS="2">
<Particle PT="1">
<![CDATA[101,1001]]>
</Particle>
<Particle PT="2">
<![CDATA[202,2002]]>
</Particle>
</TimeStep>

and so on
```

Target matrix structure is columnwise, as follows 
1st column = TimeStep TS 
2nd column = Particle PT 
3rd & 4th columns = data inside squared backets

```
1 1 100 1000
1 2 200 2000
2 1 101 1001
2 2 202 2002
```

So far I managed to do so as below

```
import numpy as np 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filename = 'ParticleTrack.xml'         

xmlfile = ET.parse(filename)

tt = xmlfile.findall(".//Particle/../../[@TS]") # picks only TimeSteps with Particles in them (might be TimeSteps with no Particles in them)

data = []
for jj in tt:
    ts = jj.get('TS') 
    pt = jj.findall(".//Particle[@PT]") 
    for ii in range(len(pt)):
        data.append([ts, pt[ii].get('PT'), (pt[ii].text.split(",")[0]), (pt[ii].text.split(",")[1])])

data=np.array(data).astype(np.float)
```

My computer has 64GB of RAM and when XML files are somewhat larger than 10 GB I ran out of memory. I am loading the whole XML file at once and writing at the same time the output matrix.

I have read about how to time and memory efficiently streaming parsing large XML files with lxml, iterparse, etc. , but I do not know how to do it with my data.

Thanks I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The digest of your question on email notifications basically contains your first paragraph, whiich says nothing about what the problem actually is. So I've deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, for large XML files, consider [**`iterparse`**](https://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm) for fast stream processing that reads tree incrementally and not all at once. In each iteration extract either from attribute dictionary or text over *TimeStep* and *Particle* element:

```py
import numpy as np
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse
#from cElementTree import iterparse          # POSSIBLY FASTER

filename = 'ParticleTrack.xml'         
data = []

for event, elem in iterparse(filename, events=("start", "end")):    
    if elem.tag == "TimeStep" and event == 'start':
        TS = elem.attrib['TS']
        elem.clear()
        
    if elem.tag == "Particle" and event == 'start':
        cdata = elem.text.split(',')
        data.append([TS, elem.attrib['PT'], cdata[0], cdata[1]])
        elem.clear()

mat = np.array(data).astype(np.float)   
print(mat)

# [[1.000e+00 1.000e+00 1.000e+02 1.000e+03]
#  [1.000e+00 2.000e+00 2.000e+02 2.000e+03]
#  [2.000e+00 1.000e+00 1.010e+02 1.001e+03]
#  [2.000e+00 2.000e+00 2.020e+02 2.002e+03]]
```

Answer (score 0):

cElementTree quite is slow, working with lxml, xpath and iters makes it a lot faster,something like this.

```
import lxml.etree as et
import numpy as np

def process_xml(filename):
    parse_xml = et.ElementTree(et.fromstring(filename)).getroot()
    items = []

    for node in parse_xml.iter('ARTIKEL'):
        ean = node.xpath('.//ARTIKELEAN/text()')
        stock1 = node.xpath('.//INSTOCK/text()')
        huidige_voorraad_excellent.append([ean,stock1])

    dfcols_stock = ['ean','stock1']
    items = pd.DataFrame(huidige_voorraad_excellent,columns=dfcols_stock)
    items = items.applymap(lambda x: x if not isinstance(x, list) else x[0] if len(x) else '')
    return items

data = process_xml(filename)
```